# How to get the original types of the properties of a reflected class?

Tags: dart, reflection

After trying several ways to get to know about the original types of the classproperties from a reflected class.
For example, this is an Animator class and Animator has four properties with it (id, name, costPerHour and reviews)

```
class Animator {
    int id;
    String name;    
    double costPerHour;
    List<Review> reviews;
}
```

...And from the Animator class, I wanna loop through the properties and I also wanna know if for example
the original type of id (is id an int, a String or an object?).

With the discovery that declarations doesn't give the needed information in this situation;

```
var _refClass = reflectClass(Animator);
var classProperties = _refClass.declarations.values.forEach((property) => {
     // property.runtimeType returns only _DeclarationMirror of _propertyname_ 
}); // What is the original type each property??
```

Help is really appreceated, thanks.

Comment: `id` appears to be an `int` here. At what point will it have been a `String`?

Comment: Not, `id` will remain an `int`. What I try to get is that the declarations also show the original type of a property: `_refClass.declarations[#name]` which is a string originally. But I try to get the original type with reflection.

Comment: Are you trying to get the type of whatever variable was originally used that eventually was passed to the `Animator` constructor to _become_ `id`? Reflection gives you metadata on an object and it's properties, not a history of the origin of every value created in your program.